# Sum of first N numbers without loops OR recursion OR multiplication

Tags: java, sum

I was given the task of writing a method in Java that computes the sum of the first `N` positive numbers. But I cannot use any loops (like `for`, `do-while` etc.), and I cannot use iteration either. The reasoning behind the latter is that it takes up a lot of heap space, even before starting any calculations. I cannot use multiplication either.

They have their own immutable `Number` class which I must return, and has instances of `0` and `1`. I cannot create any new instances, but I *can* add two instances and get the result.

So, for example, I cannot just return `n * (n + 1) / 2`, because multiplication is forbidden. I even tried doing multiplication with adding logarithms, but even if I have the answer, I cannot return it, because I cannot create the corresponding `Number` instance. So I guess I *must* use the addition function included with `Number`.

I'm supposed to solve the problem by creating instances of some immutable class I write, and passing the subtotal to the new instance. That's clear. What isn't clear to me is that at the end I would still need to use some loop or some sort of recursion, needn't I? Or is there another way?

EDIT: Here is the code for `Number`: https://pastebin.com/N8WNvmxK (`Number` is in package `f`, which I cannot modify at all)

UPDATE: It turns out that I could utilize one of the methods in the classes they provided, because it had a while loop in it. So I could do the iteration.

Comment: `(1+N)*N/2` - no loop required

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote before, I cannot create new instances of their `Number`. So I cannot return it.

Comment: you could create a horribly long tree of `if` and `elses` covering all cases, up to a certain number. Which would be very bad, but it would not loop

Comment: Yeah, true, but N should be the input of the method.

Comment: Parse the resulting Integer into binary, return a list of their Number. For example a list containing 110 for N=3.

Comment: Perhaps you should include the code of this `Number` class in the question.

Comment: @Jorge.V I need to return a `Number`. What did you mean? I thought about creating a list of all 2-power numbers, then simply creating the result by their sum. But I think they wanted something simpler.

Comment: If addition is forbidden too - I will jump out of the window

Comment: @Eran OK, I did.

Comment: The thing i think of is with 2 Threads and then alternating between them while one is waiting and the other computing and then let them switch

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Stream`s?

Comment: @Lino Good idea, but don't you need while{} for running Threads? Still... is two functions calling each other is called a recursion?

Comment: @Eran Yes, I can pretty much use anything, except the lot of restrains I told about.

Comment: @GregT well, I posted an answer using Streams.

Answer (score 2):

you should return `(N*(N+1))/2`, but this is not a java programming problem rather a basic math one.

Comment: is recursion alllowed?

Comment: @GregT, kindly read his edited statement "would still need to use some loop or some sort of recursion, needn't I?"

Comment: I wrote the question :) I mean, I'm not allowed, but I couldn't really do it without recursion.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your main problem actually is not *computing* the answer, but merely *constructing* it efficiently (other answers clearly show the formula you can use for computing).

You can construct the number using binary representation and making intermediate partial number for each `1` of the binary representation.

Say, sum from `1` to `10` is `55` which in binary is `110111` (`32` + `16` + `4` + `2` + `1`). You can compute each required power of two by adding together two copies of previos one, and then accumulate into final result.

Comment: "I guess that your main problem actually is not computing the answer, but merely constructing it efficiently" True. I thought about the same solution, but I think they want something simpler. Unfortunately, it's not as a black and white situation (it's more about software design). But +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formulae to sum first n natural numbers as : ((n**2)+n)/2

Code it in Java or any language as per your needs.

```
sum = ((n*n)+n)/2;
```

Reference: https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalNumbers.htm

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I cannot use multiplication, either (added now). But it isn't the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The actual mathematical solution was already given. Now to the legalistic means:

```
Number squareSum(Number n) {
    Number nPlus1 = n.plus(Number.ONE);
    Number prod = n.times(nPlus1);
    Number two = Number.ONE.plus(Number.ONE);
    return prod.dividedBy(two);
}
```

Number should provide the operations as methods `plus` (or `add`) and such.

To reduce overflow on the product, and if one can check with Number whether a Number is even or odd (modulo, bit-and), the division can be done on eith er N or N+1.

*(Despite problem statement there are 3 values available: 1, 0 and N.
)*

---

***After Number API was given:***

I think it is simply:

```
Number squareSum(Number n) {
    double x = n.value();
    return new Number(x * (x + 1) / 2);
}
```

That is the question was chasing for the formula N*(N+1)/2,
*and* the usage of `value`. This method is not public but package scoped,
and your answer is in the same package.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, times and dividedBy are not provided, and `Number` is a final class.

Comment: If there are no similar operations in Number, like bit/shift/array operations, then there is a problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot modify package `f` at all. I updated my question.

Comment: There are some math aspects, like `f(2N) = 4.f(N)-N` but without loops...

Answer (score 0):

return LongStream.range(1,N+1).sum():

Comment: Unfortunately I need to return a `Number`.

Comment: well internally it's iterating, so that doesn't count

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you can use `Stream`s:

```
Number result = Stream.iterate(Number.ONE, n -> n.add(Number.ONE))
                      .limit(N)
                      .reduce(Number.ZERO, Number::add);
```

Comment: That does count as iterating, even the method name says it :P

Comment: @Lino I asked the OP if Streams are allowed and the answer was yes.

Comment: Streams are allowed, but iteration is unfortunately not. Do all streams depend on iteration? (I'm not very familiar.)

Answer (score 0):

When you're not feeling bad about cheating then you can use the following method. Which on the first look doesn't look like anything useful. But it gets the Job done. Still using loops though, they are just not visible:

```
private static Number getSum(long N){
    // \u000d\u004E\u0075\u006D\u0062\u0065\u0072\u0020\u0072\u0065\u0073\u0075\u006C\u0074\u0020\u003D\u0020\u004E\u0075\u006D\u0062\u0065\u0072\u002E\u005A\u0045\u0052\u004F\u003B\u000A\u0066\u006F\u0072\u0028\u006C\u006F\u006E\u0067\u0020\u006C\u0020\u003D\u0020\u0030\u003B\u0020\u006C\u0020\u003C\u0020\u0028\u004E\u0020\u002A\u0020\u0028\u004E\u0020\u002B\u0020\u0031\u0029\u0020\u002F\u0020\u0032\u0029\u003B\u0020\u006C\u002B\u002B\u0029\u007B\u000A\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0072\u0065\u0073\u0075\u006C\u0074\u0020\u003D\u0020\u0072\u0065\u0073\u0075\u006C\u0074\u002E\u0061\u0064\u0064\u0028\u004E\u0075\u006D\u0062\u0065\u0072\u002E\u004F\u004E\u0045\u0029\u003B\u000A\u007D\u000A\u0072\u0065\u0074\u0075\u0072\u006E\u0020\u0072\u0065\u0073\u0075\u006C\u0074\u003B
}
```

This method will yield you the correct `Number`.

E.g. `getSum(4)` will return a `Number` whose value is `10.0`.

Comment: Thanks! But I think this is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Math.pow, or is it prohibited too?

```
(int) (Math.pow(n, 2) + n) / 2;
```

Comment: (n*(n+1))/2 = (n*n + n) /2 = (sqr(n) + n)/2 = (int) (Math.pow(n, 2) + n) / 2;

Comment: It IS prohibited, as I cannot create a new `Number` instance